# Is there an class informer plugin(ida pro) that works for so libraries?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering, ida

I started decompling a games .so library file recently and found that its written in c++(ida says its GNU C++). Soon i found some vtable functions like

`(retvaltype...)(argstype...)(*(_DWORD*)(this + 0x40) + 0x38)(args...)`

(prettysure they're vtable functions)

but the class informer cant be used here. It didnt appear under plugins tab like when I was decompling someshootinggame's dll.So i guess it cant be used on so libraries? If so，is there any
alternatives?

And by the way，how locate & turn this vfunc to pseudo code? Doesnt even have a sub_... name.

Comment: Is reverse engineering permitted by the license of the game? If not then this is not suitable for SO.

Comment: It did not mention about reverse engineering so ......